# yii cdbdatareader and readObject function

Tags: yii

I am trying to construct an object from a stored procedure will yii.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbDataReader

I am unsure how to use the function   $dataReader->readObject('image', $image);

to construct an object- anyone any ideas if this is the correct way or if this is very slow way of constructing objects

```
 function __construct($image) {
                print "In BaseClass constructor\n";
             }      

     public static function getImageFromAliasTitle($alias_title)
                {              
                   // $alias_title =Utils::checkEnteredData($alias_title);
                    $connection = Yii::app()->db;     
                    $command = $connection->createCommand("CALL get_associated_image_detail(:in_image_alias_title, :in_image_visible, :in_image_approved, :in_album_visible, :in_album_approved)"); 
                    $command->bindParam(":in_image_alias_title",$alias_title,PDO::PARAM_STR);  
                    $command->bindValue(":in_image_visible",'1',PDO::PARAM_STR);  
                    $command->bindValue(":in_image_approved",'Yes',PDO::PARAM_STR);  
                    $command->bindValue(":in_album_visible",'1',PDO::PARAM_STR);  
                    $command->bindValue(":in_album_approved",'Yes',PDO::PARAM_STR);



                try{
                    $dataReader = $command->query(); 

                    if($dataReader->count() >0)
                    {
                        $image = $dataReader->read();                     
                    }


                    $dataReader->readObject('image', $image);


                  //  $image = $dataReader->read();        
                    $dataReader->nextResult(); 
                    $album = $dataReader->readAll();
                    $dataReader->nextResult(); 
                    $tag = $dataReader->readAll();
                    $dataReader->nextResult(); 
                    $user_image = $dataReader->readAll();
                    $dataReader->close();
                 }

                    catch(Exception $e){                   
                        Yii::log('', CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR, 'Message Here...');
                    }

                return $image;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
foreach($row as $dataReader->readAll()){
    echo $row["image"];
}
```

if It does not help then try to print:

```
print_r($dataReader->readAll());
```